# Set username as author of comment in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm making a website where registered users are able to make a post, comment on the post as well as reply to the comments and I'm having trouble with displaying the username of whom has commented.

File home.php

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post LIMIT 3";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $id = $row['users_id'];
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_username='$id'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        echo "<div class='comment-box'>";
        echo $row['title']."<br>";
        echo $row['date_created']."<br>";
        echo $row2['users_id']."<br>";
        echo $row['content']."<br>";           
        echo "</p></div>";
        if(isset ($_SESSION["username"])){
            echo "<button type='button' id='postbtn' onclick='replyFunction()'>Reply</button>";
            include 'commentsection.php';      
        } 
    }
}
```

File makeapost.php

```
<div class="thread">
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("includes/posts.inc.php");?>"method="post">
    <h4>Create a post </h4>
    <hr></hr>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id">
    <input type="hidden" name="users_id" value="<?php echo ".$_SESSION[username].";?>">
    <input type="text" id="thetitle" name="title" placeholder="Title">
    <input type="hidden"  name="date_created"> <br>
    <textarea id="summernote" name="content"></textarea>
    <hr></hr>
    <button type="submit" id="postbutton" name="submit">Post</button>
    
  </form>
</div>
```

File posts.inc.php

```
<?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';
include 'functions.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $users_id = $_POST["users_id"];
    $content = $_POST["content"];
    $date_created = $_POST["date_created"];
    $mysqltime = date ('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO post (title, users_id, content, date_created) VALUES (?,?,?,?);";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
 
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
     header("location: ../home.php?error=stmtfailed");
     exit();
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $title, $users_id, $content, $mysqltime);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header("location: ../home.php?error=none");
     exit();
    
}
```

login.inc.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST ["submit"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    require_once 'functions.inc.php';

    if(emptyInputLogin($username, $password) !== false){
        header("location: ../home.php?error=emptyinput");
        exit();
    }

    loginUser($conn, $username, $password);

} else {
    header("location: ../home.php");
    exit();
}
```

functions.inc.php

```
function loginUser($conn, $username, $password){
    $uidExists = uidExists($conn, $username, $username);

    if($uidExists === false){
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wrongusername");
        exit();
    }

    $passwordHashed = $uidExists["users_password"];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($password, $passwordHashed);

    if($checkPwd === false){
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wrongpassword");
        exit();
    } else if ($checkPwd === true){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists["users_id"];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $uidExists["users_username"];
        $_SESSION["role"] = $uidExists["users_role"];
        header("location: ../home.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `users_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `users_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `users_username` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `users_password` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`users_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

It may have something to do with the fact that I cannot connect the right user ID from the post table to the users table, since in the users table i have columns such as (users_id(AUTO_INCREMENT), users_username)
but in post table i have (users_id). I am able to make a post and messages are inserted to the database, but theres no users shown.

Any tips on how I can improve this? Right now nothing is being displayed on home.php page, but the posts are still in the database.

Comment: You have no value in `<input type="hidden" name="post_id">`.

Comment: Does `post.users_id` contain a user ID or a username? You're comparing it with `users.users_username` instead of `users.users_id`.

Comment: You shouldn't put the username in a hidden input, since the user could change this. Use `$_SESSION['username']`, it's not as hackable.

Comment: In `home.php` you shouldn't do another query in the loop, just join the tables: `SELECT p.*, u.users_id FROM post AS p JOIN users AS u ON u.users_username = p.users_id LIMIT 3`.

Comment: @Barmar post table has only users_id column, while users table has users_id and users_username, and the input type that has name post_id is auto_increment, no need to give it a value then or?

Comment: If the post ID is auto increment, why do you have the hidden input in the first place?

Comment: Answer my question: does the `users_id` column in `posts` contain a user ID or a user name? You're treating it as a username when you perform the second query, but the column name suggests it should be an ID.

Comment: @Barmar Very true, I'm very new to php and mysql in general so I understand how to insert certain values but don't really know what I need in order to link users to specific posts, comments and replies, so I'm a little all over the place if you know what I mean. I suppose the users_id column in posts contain a user ID, only outputs 0 right now

Comment: So your second query should be `WHERE users_id='$id'`. And `echo $row2['users_id']."<br>";` should be `echo $row2['users_username']."<br>";`

Comment: @Barmar Just tried it but didn't work. Here's how it looks in mysql database:        POST post_id [AUTO_INCREMENT]
title (varchar(255))
users_id int(11)
content (varchar(500))
date_created (varchar(500)), then USERS table                                                    users_id (AUTO_INCREMENT)
users_username (tinytext)

Comment: The value of the hidden `users_id` input should be the user ID, not the user name. Do you save that in the session?

Comment: @Barmar I suppose I do not, I have only created $users_id = $_POST["users_id"]; in posts.inc.php file, must not be saved since i tried this change <input type="hidden" name="users_id" value="<?php echo ".$_SESSION[users_id].";?>">

Comment: You could either change your login code to save the user ID as well, or look up the user ID from the username in `posts.inc.php`.

Comment: @Barmar I edited the post so you could see the login.inc.php file as well as functions.inc.php, a bit confusing perhaps? since i have written  $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists["users_id"]; in functions.inc.php

Comment: Use `$_SESSION["userid"]` instead of `$_SESSION["username"]`

Comment: You'd probably find this a whole lot easier if you started with a better query. Nested queries are almost always a bad idea. Start by JOINing your users table to your posts table in your first query. You'll get all the data you need in one result set. There's no table structure here, so I can't give you a sample query.

Comment: @Barmar I managed to get the right output from the userid which says 17 ( 17th account created ) but still cant seem to display the username, tried using that SQL statement with joining tables

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I provided the table structure, any tips or improvements would be appreciated. I'm gonna start look into how i can join the tables as im quite new at this

Answer (score 0):

Working from the table definitions you posted above (which don't match your PHP code) I created this data:

post table:

| post_id | users_id | content | dateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 6 | Here's some content | 20 May 2022 |
| 15 | 7 | A message | 19 May 2022 |
| 16 | 7 | Another message | 20 May 2022 |
| 17 | 8 | I've nothing to say | 20 May 2022 |
| 18 | 9 | I said everything already. | 18 May 2022 |

Users table

| users_id | users_username | users_password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Mike | password |
| 7 | George | another password |
| 8 | Helen | passwd |
| 9 | Alice | pword |
| 10 | Bob | secret |

From this I created this query:

```
select post_id, content, date_created, u.users_username 
    from 
        post 
    join 
        (select users_username, users_id from users) u 
    on post.users_id = u.users_id
order by date_created desc
limit 3;
```

Which gives this result:

| post_id | content | date_created | users_username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | Here's some content | 20 May 2022 | Mike |
| 16 | Another message | 20 May 2022 | George |
| 17 | I've nothing to say | 20 May 2022 | Helen |

Now you can just loop through the results and create your output without the need for a nested query to retrieve data.

Note:

- This is a simple example based on your table structure and some simple data. You can include or exclude some of these columns, change the order, include or exclude more rows.
- `dateCreated` should be a `DateTime` column, not a `varchar` column
- Passwords should NOT be stored in plain text.
- You will need to consider appropriate indexing once these tables start to grow.